# Is AngularJS protected to user's input XSS attacks by default?

Tags: angularjs

I have seen that when I am adding HTML or JS content to the DB and then print it with AngularJS, like this: `{{theDataAddedToDB}}` it ignores the HTML tags and then it is protected from XSS.

Now that is nice to assume - but is it enough to be sure that my projects are XSS protected when I am using the AngularJS?

(I am talking about user input by itself, not about third party plugins or something else, just user inputs XSS).

Thanks.

Comment: Is AngularJS protected from XSS attacks?  - *No*.

Comment: So what is protected from user's input XSS?

Comment: Take a look here - https://code.google.com/archive/p/mustache-security/wikis/AngularJS.wiki , it contains more details.

Comment: I have tried: {{console.log(document.cookie)}} and it does not log the cookies..

Comment: **Be aware that marking untrusted data as safe via calls to $sce.trustAsHtml, etc is dangerous and will lead to Cross Site Scripting exploits.** For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Security - Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security#strict-contextual-escaping)

Comment: Hey, I am not asking about $sce.trustAsHtml at all.
I am just asking about default AngularJS brackets, are they safe for XSS??

Comment: @Raz try `{{toString.constructor.prototype.toString=toString.constructor.prototype.call; ["a","console.log(document.cookie)"].sort(toString.constructor)}}`

Comment: I receive the next error: Error: [$parse:lexerr]

Comment: @Raz what angularjs version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By making use of $sceProvider and $SanitizeProvider we can avoid xss attacks in angularjs.

use these library as per angular js norm:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
```

and then in script tag the code could be written like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('HelloApp', ["ngSanitize"])
.controller('HelloCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce){
$scope.name="";
$scope.processHtmlCode=function() {
$scope.helloMessage = "<h1>" + $scope.name + "</h1>";
$scope.trustedMessage =  $sce.trustAsHtml( $scope.name );
}
}])
</script>
```

Comment: Please be more specific and explain your answer.

Comment: I edited my answer as you required. Hope this piece of code helps you.

Comment: I know trustAsHtml function, I am talking about when I do not want user add HTML or JS at all, by default of AngularJS brackets tags.

BTW, when I am adding the ngSanitize depency, it will sanitze all <script> tags but not normal tags like <strong> ?

Comment: @Raz I implemented this type of code in my project to avoid xss attacks. other ways are to provide protections, through  server side, which are done by backend.

Comment: by default angularjs, not able to give protection for xss.

Comment: But when I am printing <script> tag with the angular brackets like this: {{someinput}} it does not fire a script tag, instead, it fires as a text.
does it vulerable to XSS?

Comment: script tag will work if you go with `ng-model` and then assign value through `$scope` in your script tag.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: **Be aware that marking untrusted data as safe via calls to $sce.trustAsHtml, etc is dangerous and will lead to Cross Site Scripting exploits.** For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Security - Strict Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/security#strict-contextual-escaping)